# SP2013: Display Templates, what is overrideValueRenderer doing?

Tags: display-template

What is the logic behind "overrideValueRenderer"? I see for example this javascript code in the display template:

```
var bestuurderListItemID = $getItemValue(ctx, "ListItemID");
bestuurderListItemID.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
```

What is the difference if I remove the second row code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overrideValueRenderer method will, as the name suggests, override the value retrieved from the managed property. Out-of-the-box there are a couple of default override functions available like the **$contentLineText** one.

In the **$contentLineText** the value length will be checked, and by default if it is greater than 90 characters, it will be trimmed.

So in you case, this isn't needed, because you are using it to retrieve the list item ID.

Regards,
Elio